# BIND9 excessive logging on network failure

Tags: logging, bind, devuan-linux

I had a network failure today, and in response one of my servers, running BIND, began logging all of its failed queries. Trouble is, it logged every single failure, with a retry rate of sometimes nearly 2,000 per second. By the time I realised what was going wrong and got the low-disk-space warning on /var, syslog had grown to 6GB for one day! Most of this resulted from NTP trying to sync.

2,000 retries per second is both impressive and wildly excessive, is there a config option I can use to dial this down to something more sane?

Comment: That is a whole lot of failed queries.  Are you sure that you don't have something else broken?  What does your logging look like currently?  Do you have a `logging` defined at all in your config?

Comment: @Zoredache after bringing the network back up, the machine shows syslog size of 110K from 2 hours of uptime, which is probably about right (I had to reboot it, everything crashed). And more importantly, no crazy logs from BIND after it started up. I did have logging defined for debugging reasons, but that's commented out, so it's currently disabled.